# Doesn't remove duplicate strings in the list in one instance

Tags: python

How do I make a for loop in elif choice == 2?

let's say I have the list ["egg, "eGG", "radish", "pork", "meat"] from user input, if the user decides to remove egg, both egg and eGG should be removed.

Here's my code:

```
print("  MY GROCERY LIST  ")

#function that adds items, removes items, prints the list of items, exits the program with the user's will.
def grocerylist():

    grocery_list = [""]
    grocery = True

    #while loop 
    while grocery:
        choice = str(input("=====================\nWhat would you like to do? \n1 - Add an item\n2 - Remove an item \n3 - Print entire list\n4 - Exit program\n\nChoice: "))
        #conditionals 
        #adds an item 
        if choice == "1":
            print("=====================\nADD AN ITEM\n")
            add_item = str(input("What would you like to add? \nItem name: ")).format() #format function 
            grocery_list.append(add_item)
        #removes an item
        elif choice == "2":
            print("=====================\nREMOVE AN ITEM\n")
            remove_item = str(input("What would you like to remove? \nItem name: ")).format() #format function 
            grocery_list.remove(remove_item)
        #prints the entire list
        elif choice == "3":
            print("=====================\nPRINTING LIST...")
            #for loop to iterate grocery_list
            for i in grocery_list:
               print(i)
        #terminates the program
        elif choice == "4":
            print("=====================\nTerminating program...")
            break
        else:
            pass

#calling of function
grocerylist()
```

I tried using a for loop but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to loop over all the items in the array, and then use call the `lower()` function on each element in the array list. This will make all the characters in an element lowercase and then you can compare. You would also have to lowercase the user input to compare correctly.

```
elif choice == "2":
    print("=====================\nREMOVE AN ITEM\n")
    remove_item = str(input("What would you like to remove? \nItem name: "))
    i = 0
    while i < len(grocery_list):
        if grocery_list[i].lower() == remove_item.lower():
            grocery_list.pop(i)
        else:
            i += 1
```

However, I would recommend using another array, and then appending the results that do not match the item you are trying to remove. The resulting `tempArray` will contain only the remaining items.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a list while iterating over it is a bad idea. It leads to unexpected behavior. Instead, generate a new list with a list comprehension, and if you want to, assign that back to your original variable.

E.g.

```
>>> lst = ["egg", "eGG", "radish", "pork", "meat"]
>>> lst = [item for item in lst if item.lower() != "egg"]
>>> lst
['radish', 'pork', 'meat']
>>>
```